# What is the use case for the Bash variable $_?

Tags: bash

The Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide mentions the [internal Bash variable](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/internalvariables.html) `$_`:

> Special variable set to final argument of previous command executed.

The document shows some examples but does not explain, why it is necessary to save the last argument in a special variable. What is the use case for this variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I find it useful to avoid re-typing a long argument passed to a sequence of commands.

My common use cases are sequences like these:

```
mkdir blahblahblah
cd $_
```

or

```
svn add a/long/path/to/the/file
svn ci $_
```

Comment: you can use ctrl-alt-. to the same effect (it pastes the last argument of the previous command where your pointer is)

Comment: @AaronGOUZIT In fact only `alt` + `.` is required

Comment: @arco444 oh, I actually meant `alt-shift-;`, because I'm on an azerty keyboard and need to press `shift-;` to produce the `.`.

Comment: Run `bind -p | grep yank-last-arg` to see which key binding, if any, is used.

Comment: I see. It seems to be a relic of bygone times before [readline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Readline) has been invented.

Answer (score -2):

It just returns last command line argument of a command. For example:

```
 $ ls -a -A -b -c >> /dev/null
 $ echo $_
 -c
```

Comment: I think OP is asking *why* - not what